# Swift decodable : check is a nested structure is present

Tags: swift4, decodable

I have a JSON data that goes something like this. I have used a separate structure approach rather than having nested keys for very structure  in a single one. The point to be noted is that the keys in the Given Json are not consistent and may be absent. Hence a check has to be made for each key before trying to parse it with the built structure.

```
 {  "ProductInfo": [
      {
        "productCode": "ABC",
        "productWeight": "2.3",
      }
    ],
    "ProductService": [
      {
        "serviceCode": "00",
        "serviceSite": 0
      }],

"ProductName": "StackSite"
}
```

**to Parse this I have created swift structure like these**

```
struct ProductStructure: Decodable{
var ProductInfo: productInfo
var ProductService: [productService]
var ProductName:String

enum ProductStructureKeys: String , CodingKey{
case ProductInfo
case ProductService
case ProductName

}

struct productInfo : Decodable {
   var productCode:String
   var productWeight:String
}

struct ProductService : Decodable {
    var serviceCode:String
    var serviceSite: Int
}


**// the decoder for the Main Structure**
extension ProductStructure{
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

let container = try decoder.container(
      keyedBy: ProductStructureKeys.self)

//checks if product name key is present
 let product: String = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: . ProductName)


*//What code should I put here to check if my other two structures are present and parse them if they are present.* 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to declare the properties `productInfo` and `productService` as optional (and with names starting with a lowercase letter). By the way **both** objects are arrays

```
struct ProductStructure: Decodable {
    let productInfo: [ProductInfo]?
    let productService: [ProductService]?
    let productName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case productInfo = "ProductInfo"
        case productService = "ProductService"
        case productName = "ProductName" 
    }

    struct ProductInfo : Decodable {
        let productCode: String
        let productWeight: String
    }

    struct ProductService : Decodable {
        let serviceCode: String
        let serviceSite: Int
    }
}
```

If the key `serviceCode` in `ProductService` can be missing, too, declare the property the same way as optional

```
 let serviceCode: String?
```

A custom initializer is not needed, assuming `data` contains the JSON as `Data`

```
let productStructure = try decoder.decode(ProductStructure.self, from: data)
```

Comment: The keys in the  productStructure are optional keys from an API perspective i.e that key may or may not be present in the JSON response. If I try to decode the structure directly without a key present the structure would collapse.
 I know how to make a check for native keys.(As I have shown above) I am looking for how to make the same verification for a nested structure

Comment: If the keys `ProductInfo` or `ProductService` are missing the values are not decoded (property is `nil`). If the properties **in** the (sub)structs can be missing, too, declare them also as optionals. The behavior is exactly the same as using `decodeIfPresent` in a custom initializer.

Comment: I am accepting this answer since this addresses my requirement. However I  am confused that if the answer is so straight forward then whats the need of decodeIfPresent

Comment: Once again if you have to write a custom initializer for example if the JSON contains a heterogenous array with multiple types you can use `decodeIfPresent` to skip missing keys.